# theano: gradient where cost is imag(x)

Tags: theano

If I have a cost that is the imaginary part of a complex number, trying to obtain the gradient with theano I get the following error:

`TypeError: Elemwise{imag,no_inplace}.grad illegally  returned an integer-valued variable. (Input index 0, dtype complex128)`

Is it not possible to use the imaginary part as cost despite it being a real-valued cost?

---

Edit. Minimal working example

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
a = T.zscalar('a')
f = function([a], T.grad(T.imag(a),a))
```

I would expect this to work as T.imag(a) is a real scalar cost..

Comment: Does the information on this (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/proposals/complex_gradient.html) page help? If not, can you edit your question to include some minimal executable code illustrating the problem please?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Thanks. I think it doesn't resolve my problem as in my case the cost is scalar. I've added an example.

Comment: I don't think gradients can be evaluated through functions of complex numbers, *wherever* they appear in the graph. The fact that it isn't at the end doesn't matter, I think. In many cases you can replace the complex numbers by appropriate real ones, possibly of double the dimensionality (but same space in memory). Then it should work.