# How to compute the gradient of a complex quantity with respect to a real variable in theano?

Tags: python, theano

Complex numbers in theano are not fully implemented yet, as discussed for example [in this groups.google post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/theano-users/G9JGCVtR79c/pSdgCFa5aWAJ) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31731711/4063051).
However, given that some support *does* seem to exist, I am trying to understand what can actually be done at the moment.

Consider for example this very simple code:

```
x = T.dscalar('x')
y = 2j * x
gy = T.grad(y, x)
f = theano.function([x], gy)
f(1.234)
```

that is, derivative with respect to the (real) scalar `x` of `a * x` with `a` some complex number.

The above code does not produce a result, complaining that

```
Casting from complex to real is ambiguous: consider real(), imag(), angle() or abs()
```

How can this code be made to work?

---

Here is the simple implementation I managed to get to work:

```
x = T.dscalar('x')
y_R = T.real(2j) * x
y_I = T.imag(2j) * x
gy_R = T.grad(y_R, x)
gy_I = T.grad(y_I, x)
gy = gy_R + 1j * gy_I
f = theano.function([x], gy)
f(1.234)
# array(2j)
```

basically, separate the complex constant into real and imaginary part, compute the gradient separately and only at the end sum them to get the complex result.
The problem with this method is that it doesn't work if we try a more complex example, like computing the gradient with respect to `x` of `expm(1j * x * H)` for some matrix `H`:

```
x = T.dscalar('x')
expH = T.slinalg.expm(1j * x * H)
expH_flat = T.flatten(expH)
expH_flat_R = T.real(T.flatten(expH))
expH_flat_I = T.imag(T.flatten(expH))
def fn(i, mat, x):
    return T.grad(mat[i], x)
J_R, updates = theano.scan(fn, sequences=T.arange(expH_flat_R.shape[0]), non_sequences=[expH_flat_R, x])
J_I, updates = theano.scan(fn, sequences=T.arange(expH_flat_I.shape[0]), non_sequences=[expH_flat_I, x])
expH_J_R = J_R.reshape(expH.shape)
expH_J_I = J_I.reshape(expH.shape)
expH_J = expH_J_R + 1j * expH_J_I
f = theano.function([x], expH_J)
f(2)
```

which returns

```
TypeError: Elemwise{real,no_inplace}.grad illegally  returned an integer-valued variable. (Input index 0, dtype complex128)
```

If this cannot be achieved at all with theano (like for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36700835/4063051) seems to suggest), is it for some particular reason, like fundamental difficulties of sort?

Comment: I think the answer to the last statement is your first one: "Complex numbers in theano are not fully implemented yet." certainly the word **yet** would imply that it is a work in progress to update the library so that all the internals will cooperate with complex numbers.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen well, it could very be that I'm wrong and it will not be implemented at all, the *yet* was just my optimistic guess. What I mean to ask is, given that I'm sure it is implementable in principle, was it not done due to simple lack of interest, or because it would need some major, fundamental changes in the code structure?

Comment: ok, that I can't answer.  I'd even wonder if there exists an objective answer at all or if the exact answer you are looking for is opinion based.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen if there is a method to do this I see such an answer as highly *non* opinion based.. and same if there is no such thing, maybe because of some fundamental (maybe mathematical?) difficulty in doing it

Comment: As of 2020, complex gradient are still not implemented in `Theano`. I guess the project has been abandoned.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś indeed, afaik development stopped after the release of v1.0 back in 2017

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is simply not possible natively (and likely won't be in the future, considering the development of Theano stopped in 2017).
One way around it is to remap every complex matrix into the larger real matrix and perform all operations on the bigger matrix (some care will be needed to redefine the various operations).
A possible mapping is `A -> [[A_R, -A_I], [A_I, A_R]]`.